# Something confusing about non-greedy regex match

Tags: ruby, regex

I wrote a piece of ruby code like below

```
  #! /usr/bin/ruby
    s = "[[abc]]"  
    if(s =~ /\[(.+)*?\]/)
        puts $1
    end
    if(s =~ /\[(.+?)\]/)
        puts $1
    end
```

its output is:

```
[abc
[abc
```

then I change variable s

```
  s = "[[abc]]]"
```

and the rest part remains the same, but now the result is

```
[abc]
[abc
```

Why this happens? Could anyone explain to me about this?

Comment: I think this may have something to do with the difference between +? and *? these two non-greedy quantifiers?

Comment: I have never used ruby, but your regex is not non greedy. The `.+` is still eventually greedy.

Comment: @npinti then why in case 2 it didn't match [abc]] as what it would do in a greedy case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if someone here will be able to explain this behaviour. I checked with [Regexr](http://regexr.com?30te9) and there the regex behaves like you are expecting it.

But

```
\[(.+)*?\]
```

is just a horribly bad designed expression. What should `(.+)*` match? Thats nesting quantifiers and it could find a valid match in many variations. Now worse, making the outer quantifier lazy, what should happen?

If you want to have greedy matching use

```
\[(.+)\]
```

if you want to have lazy matching, use

```
\[(.+?)\]
```

**But never nest quantifiers, so that they can find many possible solutions, this leads to [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html), or see here a [blog post by Jeff Atwood on Coding Horror about Regex Performance](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/regex-performance.html)**